# Mirth Connect SQL Server Error : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: mirth

I am trying to insert into SQL Server DateTime field. Trying simple scenario of one table having datetime column named start_date only.

Query I am trying is

```
INSERT INTO test (start_date) values (${start_date})
```

start_date is channelMap variable of Type java.util.Date , It was created using  :

```
var start_date = DateUtil.getDate('yyyyMMddHHmmss', msg['date'].toString());
```

Here start_date is of java.util.Date, why mirth treats it as String when it tries to insert into database ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the conversion even in SQL. Hope it helps

```
var start_date = msg['PID']['PID.7']['PID.7.1'].toString(); // 19831123 - YYYYMMDD format
try {
  sql="INSERT INTO test (start_date) values (convert(datetime,'" + start_date + "',5))";
  logger.info(sql);
  rst = dbConn.executeUpdate(sql);  
}
catch(err) {
  logger.info('ERR: ' + err);
}
```

Out in DB will be below.

```
select * from test
start_date |
----------
1983-11-23 00:00:00.000
```

**2nd Approach**

If you still want to use util try below

```
var start_date = msg['PID']['PID.7']['PID.7.1'].toString(); // 19831123 - YYYYMMDD format
/* 
Input is yyyyMMdd and 
output is yyyyMMddHHmmss format
*/
var datestring = DateUtil.convertDate('yyyyMMdd', 'yyyyMMddHHmmss', start_date); 
try {
  sql="INSERT INTO test (start_date) values ('" + start_date + "')";
  logger.info(sql);
  rst = dbConn.executeUpdate(sql);  
}
catch(err) {
  logger.info('ERR: ' + err);
}
```

Comment: If you still want to use java util functions. Try below.

Comment: If you still want to use util try below

var start_date = msg['PID']['PID.7']['PID.7.1'].toString(); // 19831123 - YYYYMMDD format
/* 
Input is yyyyMMdd and 
output is yyyyMMddHHmmss format
*/
var datestring = DateUtil.convertDate('yyyyMMdd', 'yyyyMMddHHmmss', start_date); 
try {
  sql="INSERT INTO test (start_date) values ('" + start_date + "')";
  logger.info(sql);
  rst = dbConn.executeUpdate(sql);  
}
catch(err) {
  logger.info('ERR: ' + err);
}

Answer (score 0):

I believe your data is inserting in DB as `'Mon Feb 19 09:25:16 IST 1968'` along with quotes.

I used formatDate function, but data inserted into DB will be like `1968-02-19 09:25:16`

```
var pidDate = msg['PID']['PID.7']['PID.7.1'].toString();
var value = DateUtil.getDate("yyyyMMddHHmmss",pidDate);
var data = DateUtil.formatDate("yyyyMMddHHmmss", value)
channelMap.put("start_date",data);
```

Inserting to DB:

```
    var dateValue = $('start_date')
    dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection(dbDriver, dbAddress, userName,passwd);
    result = dbConn.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO test (startdate) values ('"+dateValue+"')");
```

I'm sending date value as **19680219092516**,inside DB value is **1968-02-19 09:25:16**.Datatype of my DB is DateTime type.

the `getDate` function returns a **java.util.Date** object, but when I tried with `getCurrentDate` function, it returns a formatted String. I guess formatting the date object is one way of inserting data into DB.